# Use one intent twice back to back

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a chatbot with the following intended structure-

...
**bot:** here are some questions-
    1. what is programming?
    2. what is dialogflow?
    3. what is a context?
    Please reply with a number of the question to know the answer.
**user:** 2
**bot:** Dialogflow is a chatbot building platform
Here are some more questions you might have-
4.What is an intent?
5.what is fulfillment?
reply with question number to know the answer-
**user:** 5
**bot:** fulfillment is .........
...

(and so on)

Here , I have fetched the questions and answers from firebase through fulfillment. I have one intent that takes question number as input, then the webhook shows the answer to that question and shows more questions after it.
The problem is- when the user sends the question number second time, the intent is not triggered.

The name of the intent is `showAnswer` and the contexts are set as shown in the image-
[image: contexts of showAnswer]

What I have done is- the input and output context for its own follow-up are put here (`showAnswer-followup`). So that it can be its own follow-up intent.

The problem is- When do the above context trick, it does not respond even the first time. When I don't put the context(`showAnswer-followup`) in the input context area, it works. but only once. The second time the user sends a question number, it does not recognize it.

I want this intent to recognize the second (question number) input by the user too.
What is wrong here, and how can I make this loop?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that for an Intent to be triggered, *all* the Input Contexts must match. So since you are only setting `showAnswer-followup` in the Output Context of that Intent, it will never trigger.

It isn't clear why you require a Followup Intent at all. You can maintain the valid questions in a context (which you just use for storage) and have an Intent that triggers on a number. Your Intent Handler can check the number, update which ones are valid, and return an answer.

(As an aside, it seems very non-conversational to just have the user reply with numbers.)